# Visualizar fuentes Powerline en VIM sobre terminal/(terminator) Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, fuentes, vim

Hola me gustaría saber que configuración debo de agregar a /.vimrc para que las fuentes Powerline funcionen correctamente en Vim, desde la terminal.
Mi configuración es esta y preferiría que se vea como en la segunda imagen.

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

set wrap
set mouse=a
set number

let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_buffers = 0
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_tabs = 1

set encoding=utf-8

set guifont=ProFont\ for\ Powerline:h12
let g:Powerline_symbols = 'fancy'
set encoding=utf-8
set t_Co=256
set fillchars+=stl:\ ,stlnc:\
set term=xterm-256color
set termencoding=utf-8
```

Ya tengo las fuentes Powerline, las agregue a la cache, pero aun se ve de esta forma

[image: Captura uno]

Preferiría que se vean estos símbolos.

[image: Captura 2]

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Has probado cambiando la fuente que usa tu terminal?

Comment: A mi me funciono esto: https://askubuntu.com/a/283909

Comment: Ok, gracias @PanchoJay como mencionaste, cargar las fuentes resulto ser la solución, al final solo era volver a cargar la fuente Powerline desde Terminator, cerrar y volver a cargar todo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como menciono @PanchoJay en su respuesta. Al final pude resolver la configuración de fuentes Powerline en VIM con Terminator sin configurar las fuentes en la configuración de ~/.vimrc con esta configuracion:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on

set encoding=utf-8
set wrap
set mouse=a
set number

let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_buffers = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_tabs = 1

let g:airline_powerline_fonts=1

" Always show statusline
set laststatus=2
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debí cerrar VIM y volver a cargar la fuente Powerline desde Terminator.
Gracias.